# Matlab ode45 internal step

Tags: matlab, solver, ode45

I'm having doubts at how to use `ode45` since I know it uses an internal variable step size. For instance, in my particular case I have a model of ODE's and I use a sampling time of 5 minutes. Hence, inside my main simulation loop I have the following line to obtain the output of my model by solving it using `ode45`:

```
[T,X] = ode45(@(t,x) model(t,x,u,data),[t t+scenario.Ts],x0);
```

Where `u` are inputs of the model, `data` is a structure with parameters, `x0` are the initial conditions at the current time step and `[t t+scenario.Ts]` is the initial and final time. My doubt is that between `t` and `t+scenario.Ts` the `ode45`-solver uses variable time steps and thus the way I introduce my input actions `u` may be affected. Hence, I understand that a value of a particular input `u` is kept constant through the internal time steps between `[t t+scenario.Ts]`. Then, if I have for instance a flux, i.e. water into a tank, the time step has a direct effect to this `u`.

Let me explain this a little more with an example. If over `[t t+scenario.Ts]` I know that `u(1) = 10`. Then the real input I should use is `u(1)=10/(# of time steps between [t0 tend])`. However, since the internal step is variable which input do I have to use?

I hope you understand my problem and can help me out.

Comment: @ykaragol If formatting code in a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12534423), please format all of it the next time. Otherwise your edit could be declined as no improvement whatsoever...

Comment: Hard to say much without seeing the code for `model` (or a representative runnable example). It looks like you may be you're trying to vary a parameter with respect to time. You may be creating a stiff system which can result in inefficient and even incorrect results. Your `model` function should not be a function of the number of time steps. `u` should be a function of `t` or your state vector `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You should formulate the inputs such that it is independent of the time- discretization. This shouldn't be a problem if your equations are formulated in continuous time. If the control variable is not constant, then you should be make it explicitly dependent of `t` and write a function `u(t)`.

If my answer is not sufficient to help you out, please add more details about your application, especially the dynamical model that you are simulating. Then we can help you further.